# Nominatim search result difference between IE and Chrome

Tags: nominatim

When searching for specific addresses in Nominatim I see different results in IE compared to Chrome. For example:

Im Singes 1 63225 Langen Deutschland

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Im+Singes+1+63225+Langen+Deutschland&polygon_geojson=1&format=xml
```

the Url in both browsers is identical. In IE I get the following place as result

```
<place
    type="residential"
    class="highway"
    importance="0.63"
    display_name="Im Singes, Linden, Langen, Landkreis Offenbach, Regierungsbezirk Darmstadt, Hessen, 63225, Deutschland"
    lon="8.68072"
    lat="49.9842571"
    geojson="{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[8.6814915,49.9844593],[8.6812535,49.9844064],[8.6810239,49.9843473],[8.68072,49.9842571],[8.6800859,49.9840417]]}"
    boundingbox="49.9840417,49.9844593,8.6800859,8.6814915"
    place_rank="26"
    osm_id="141557253"
    osm_type="way"
    place_id="97786309"
/>
```

and in Chrome it is

```
<place
    place_id="96505241"
    osm_type="way"
    osm_id="141557254"
    place_rank="26"
    boundingbox="49.9845947,49.9849051,8.6816261,8.6848355"
    geojson="{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[8.6848355,49.984848],[8.684728,49.9848833],[8.6846498,49.9848986],[8.6845552,49.9849051],[8.6844579,49.9848991],[8.6831001,49.9847536],[8.6816261,49.9845947]]}" 
    lat="49.9847536"
    lon="8.6831001"
    display_name="Im Singes, Linden, Langen, Landkreis Offenbach, Regierungsbezirk Darmstadt, Hesse, 63225, Germany"
    class="highway"
    type="residential"
    importance="0.52"
/>
```

Two different records with slightly different coordinates. Any idea?

Comment: weird (and interesting). **curl** and **wget** seem to give the same result as your IE example, and **Firefox** gives the same result as Chrome. I can't check IE. (curl/wget are command line tools for fetching web resources without using a browser). I thought it might be a subtle difference in encoding the URLs, but there aren't any non-latin characters in your place name...